# How can I add a search domain in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, domain

How can I add a search domain in Windows 7?

For example, if I typed `mail` into a URL, it'd automatically add `.google.com` when I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. On my Mac, this is equivalent to going into my network settings and adding a search domain.

Comment: Search domain? To search what from where? Windows Search? DNS? ...?

Comment: for example, if i typed 'mail' into my url, i want it to automatically add '.google.com' for me when i hit enter.

Comment: on my mac, this is equivalent to going into my network settings and adding a search domain.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

- Go to *Control Panel → Network and Internet → Network and Sharing Center*.
- Click on *Change Adapter Settings* on the left side.
- Right-click on your network adapter (normally "Local Area Connection" or "Wireless Network Connection") and select *Properties*.
- Select *Internet Protocol version 4 (TCP/IPv4)* and click on the *Properties* button.
- On the *General* tab, click on the *Advanced…* button.
- In the *Append this DNS suffixes* list, add the domains you want, like `google.com`.

I just tried and it worked for me. By typing "`mail`<kbd>ENTER</kbd>" in Firefox, I was sent to Google Mail.